# Laravel 5.4 - Update an existing record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm struggling to update an existing record through an Eloquent Model in Laravel 5.4

I have for creating a record that works perfectly fine, I took it and modified it to try and update the record:

```
public function commitEdit ($char_edit_id) 
    {


    $edited_character = \DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', $char_edit_id)->first();


    $edited_character->campaign_id = 1;

    $edited_character->character_name = request('characterName');

    $edited_character->Race = request('race');

    $edited_character->Sub_Race = request('subRaceField');

    $edited_character->Class = request('class');

    $edited_character->Level = request('level');

    $edited_character->Strength = request('strength');

    $edited_character->Dexterity = request('dexterity');

    $edited_character->Constitution = request('constitution');

    $edited_character->Intelligence = request('intelligence');

    $edited_character->Wisdom = request('wisdom');

    $edited_character->Charisma = request('charisma');

    $levelVar = request('level');

    if ($levelVar >= 4) {
    $edited_character->Proficiency = 2;
    } else if ($levelVar >= 8) {
    $edited_character->Proficiency = 3;
    }


    $edited_character->Trained_Skills = request('skillsField');

    $edited_character->Languages = request('languagesField');


    $edited_character->Hit_Die = 1;

    $edited_character->max_HP = request('max-hp');

    $edited_character->Alignment = request('alignment');

    $edited_character->Armor_Class = request('armor-class');

    $edited_character->Initiative = request('initiative');

    $edited_character->Speed = request('speed');

    $edited_character->Background = request('background');



    $edited_character->update();

    return redirect('./characters');
```

That gives this error:
Call to undefined method stdClass::update()

I have tried using save() but I get the same error with save() instead of update()

Thanks in advance c:

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

> If you just need to retrieve a single row from the database table, you may use the first method. This method will return a single StdClass object:

`$edited_character` is a `stdClass`, no Eloquent model.

You can try this code:

```
public function commitEdit ($char_edit_id) 
{
    $edited_character = \DB::table('characters')->where('char_id', $char_edit_id)->update([
        'campaign_id' => 1,
        'character_name' => request('characterName'),
        'Race' => request('race'),
        //others property
    ]);
}
```

Or create `Characters` model which will be extends from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` and use `save` method:

```
public function commitEdit ($char_edit_id) 
{
    $edited_character = Characters::where('char_id', $char_edit_id)-first();
    //your code with properties
    $edited_character->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
public function commitEdit ($char_edit_id) 
{
    $edited_character = Characters::find($char_edit_id);
    $edited_character->character_name = request('characterName');

    $edited_character->Race = request('race');

    $edited_character->Sub_Race = request('subRaceField');

    $edited_character->Class = request('class');

    $edited_character->Level = request('level');

    $edited_character->Strength = request('strength');

    $edited_character->Dexterity = request('dexterity');

    $edited_character->Constitution = request('constitution');

    $edited_character->Intelligence = request('intelligence');

    $edited_character->Wisdom = request('wisdom');

    $edited_character->Charisma = request('charisma');

    $levelVar = request('level');

    if ($levelVar >= 4) {
    $edited_character->Proficiency = 2;
    } else if ($levelVar >= 8) {
    $edited_character->Proficiency = 3;
    }


    $edited_character->Trained_Skills = request('skillsField');

    $edited_character->Languages = request('languagesField');


    $edited_character->Hit_Die = 1;

    $edited_character->max_HP = request('max-hp');

    $edited_character->Alignment = request('alignment');

    $edited_character->Armor_Class = request('armor-class');

    $edited_character->Initiative = request('initiative');

    $edited_character->Speed = request('speed');

    $edited_character->Background = request('background');



    if($edited_character->save()){
        return redirect('./characters');
     }else{
         // show error message
       }
}
```